# Constant sheaf with value the empty set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Let X be a topological space. Is there such a thing as the constant sheaf on X with value the empty set?  That is, a sheaf that assigns to each open set U the set of maps from U to the empty set and to each inclusion the empty map?

I ask because I am trying to show that the projection map from the etale space of a locally constant sheaf on X to X, defined to send a germ at a point x to the point x, is a covering map. It's not clear to me that this map is surjective. That is, why can't there be an x in X such that there are no sections over any neighborhood of x?

Comment: The sheaf that assigns to each open $U$ the set of maps $U\to\varnothing$ will send each *nonempty* U to the empty set, but it will send the empty open set $U$ to a $1$-element set (whose member is the empty function). A nice exercise is to show that *every* sheaf on any space must send the empty open set to a $1$-element set. (Hint: Consider the empty cover of $\varnothing$, not the cover $\{\varnothing\}$ but the cover $\varnothing$.)

Comment: This is true. But does this mean this sheaf is not a constant sheaf?

Comment: I usually use "constant presheaf" to mean that the same value is assigned to all open sets, and I use "constant sheaf" to mean the associated sheaf of a constant presheaf.  With this terminology (which I think is fairly standard), your example is a constant sheaf but not a constant presheaf.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empty sheaf $E$ is exactly as you described it. Note that $E(\emptyset)$ has exactly one element (this is in fact true for all sheaves), and that if $U \neq \emptyset$, we have $E(U) = \emptyset$.

The corresponding etale map is the trivial map from the empty space to $X$. $\DeclareMathOperator{id}{id}$

In general, given a set $A$, the "constant presheaf of $A$" defined by $P(U) = A$ and $P(U \subseteq V) = \id_A$ for all $U, V$ open, and its associated locally constant sheaf $E$, the associated etale space over $X$ will be $p_2 : A \times X \to X$, where $A$ has the discrete topology.